# Conditional Query with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Im using LINQ to XML to delete and inserts tags into an xml document. One situation I often encounter is that I have a *preference* of where I want to insert a particular tag but that preference can't always be met. For example here I'd prefer to insert it right after the last element with the same CalendarCode:

```
elements = from e in calendarDocument.Descendants("ExceptionalSessions") where e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode select e;

elements.Last().AddAfterSelf(sessionElement);
```

However sometimes the element to be inserted is the first of its kind in that document with that CalendarCode so the extra condition:

```
where e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode
```

will create an empty result set. In that case I'd like to use a query *without* that additional condition. This is a one time thing though, after inserting an element with that calendar code I'd like the NEXT element with the same CalendarCode to be inserted after the first one... in that case I'd want to use the query *with* that additional condition.

I tried a few ways to solve this but they all look very crude and possibly inefficient and I couldnt help but think there's a better way.

Can anyone give me an idea if they ever encountered this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to evaluate the condition and decide the target prior to adding it. Using a separate method for clarity, possibly something like this (not tested):

```
private XElement GetCalendarTargetNode(XElement source, XElement calendarCode)
        {
            var exceptionalSessions = source.Descendants("ExceptionalSessions");
            return exceptionalSessions.LastOrDefault(e => e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode) ?? exceptionalSessions.Last();
        }
```

Or a slightly different implementation:

```
private XElement GetCalendarTargetNode(XElement source, XElement calendarCode)
        {
            var exceptionalSessions = source.Descendants("ExceptionalSessions");
            return exceptionalSessions.Where(e => e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode).DefaultIfEmpty(exceptionalSessions.Last()).Last();
        }
```

And use it:

```
var target = GetCalendarTargetNode(calendarDocument, calendarCode);
target.AddAfterSelf(sessionElement);
```

**EDIT:**
Or a simplified version without using extra methods:

```
    var exceptionalSessions = calendarDocument.Descendants("ExceptionalSessions");
    var target = exceptionalSessions.Where(e => e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(exceptionalSessions.Last());
    target.Last().AddAfterSelf(sessionElement);
```

Comment: did you mean
var target = exceptionalSessions.Where(e => e.Element("CalendarCode") == calendarCode)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(exceptionalSessions);  

without the Last(). Thank you though, this seems like a fit for what I need

Comment: also is this still considered a linq query without the "from" ... "select"?

Comment: Well, DefaultIfEmpty() actually takes the default element that should be returned when empty, I just assumed it was the last element in exceptionalSessions since exceptionalSessions is IEnumerable<XElement>). And yes, it's still Linq, method chaining is just alternate syntax for the same thing.

Comment: hmm DefaultIfEmpty is kind of confusing me. You pass in a single element and is returns a collection? The only way I can understand this is if it just returns the original result set. So after call DefaultIfEmpty() exceptionalSessions and target would be identical result sets (if theres no matching calendar code elements)???

Or will target simple have one element?

Comment: Precisely, DefaultIfEmpty() will do the check for you, if the incoming Enumerable doesn't have any elements it will yield the default you provide, but still return an IEnumerable with just that default element.